# MySQL: Count items by categories

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, counter, minimum

I've created a table that holds items according to categories:

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(30)         | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| category   | varchar(30)         | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| timestamp  | timestamp           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| data       | mediumblob          | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

Old data is deleted using a [sliding window technique](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/implementing-a-circular-buffer-sliding-window-in-mysql#comment33749_20036), meaning that only the last `N` items in each category are kept in the table.

How can I keep track the total number of the items per category, and the timestamp of the first item in the category?

**Edit** - `COUNT` and `MIN` on the original table won't work, because this is a Sliding Window data structure meaning that the first items have already been deleted.

Comment: can't you create a table that holds the counter and the first data?

Comment: I can. I'm struggling with the stored procedure that populates the other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly you need to keep a separate table when you delete the records.  Your table should summarize the categories and include the fields:

- Category first start time
- Total number of items in the category

and so on.

When you go to delete, you need to update this table.  In general, I prefer to use stored procedures to handle database maintenance, so this code could be added to the stored procedure.  Others prefer triggers, so you could have a delete trigger that does the same thing.

Comment: +1 That's true. Could you give an outline of such procedure? I am not fluent with stored procedures syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try with `SELECT count(id) FROM table GROUP BY category`

Comment: Will not work - note that this is a sliding window, so the oldest items are deleted.